# Is IBM's OS V7R2 the same as AIX?

Tags: ibm, aix, ibm-midrange

Im working with a an iSeries Power 7+ server and the operating system is V7R2, is this a version of AIX or a completely different OS?

Comment: It's either [IBM *i*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i), aka OS/400 or AIX. Can you run `uname -a` (or `oslevel`)? If yes, it's AIX, IBM i apparently has a command named `GO LICPGM ` for this (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21634678). Theoretically, it could even be RHEL 7.2, but this would be a strange way to describe this OS.

Comment: Appreciate it, trying to determine what I need to do to compile libcurl into functioning DLL on this OS, but there is so much non-specific info out there on iSeries stuff it was tough to determine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is one of the operating systems supported on IBM Power Systems alongside AIX and Linux as well as on IBM PureSystems alongside AIX, Linux and Windows. [source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i)

V7R1,2,3 is a sucessor of OS/400.

A fact on the name;

> When IBM announced the new Power Systems line of servers on April 2,
>   2008, they renamed the operating system from i5/OS to IBM i[3] and
>   changed the version identifier format from VxRxMx (Version, Release,
>   Modification, e.g. V6R1M0) to the more standard format (e.g. 6.1).

Comment: The part about IBM having changed this versioning scheme prevented me from outright stating it's OS/400. Most likely it's correct though and this is just a not-yet changed part of the OS. On the other side: AIX is somewhat familiar if you know any Unix type OS (like Linux) - OS/400 is *very* different from what I understand (unfortunately, I've never used any of this stuff).

Answer (score 1):

AIX and OS/400 are two completely different animals. The only significant relation between the two are that they are both developed by IBM.

AIX is IBM's version of UNIX. OS/400 (i5/Os) is not a Unix operating system. 
It is the successor to IBM's System 36/38, completely different operating system.

OS/400 does have a Unix based shell that can be used to port and run AIX applications, but that is about it.